# Why do we use tags in Riemann integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Why do we use tags and tagged partitions for a Riemann integral?

Answer (score 4):

Because Riemann started with the mean value theorem 
$$F(t_{i+1})-F(t_i)=f(t_i^*)(t_{i+1}-t_i),\qquad (f=F')$$ 
for some $t_i^*\in(t_i,t_{i+1})$, so that in the sum over a partition $a=t_0<t_1<…<t_n=b$ one gets
$$
F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_i^*)(t_{i+1}-t_i).
$$

Thus among all the tagged partitions of $[a,b]$ there is one that gets it "exactly right" for $f$, and under the usual conditions on $f$ (bounded variation etc.) all other tagged partitions will give values close to it if the granularity is fine enough.

Comment: So in other words tagged partitions result in a more accurate answer? I still don't get how the mean value theorem relates with this

Comment: It just adds more theoretical flexibility. Even in the upper/lower Riemann/Darboux sums, the maxima and minima over the intervals of the partition are at unknown inner points.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we define the Riemann integral in the simplest way, using the left hand rectangle rule with uniform partitions. What bad things happen? Well, the integral of $1$ on $[0,1]$ is still $1$, which is good. But what about the integral of the function which is $1$ on the rationals in $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere? With the left hand rectangle rule, this function *also* has integral $1$. Consequently the integral of the function which is $1$ on the irrationals in $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere has integral *zero*. Now that doesn't make any sense: that means that our notion of integral is somehow telling us that the rationals are "bigger" than the irrationals. But it should really be the other way around, if the comparison makes sense at all.

We can have even worse things happen. Consider the function which is $1$ on the rationals in $[0,\sqrt{2}]$ and zero elsewhere. Intuitively, the rationals should be distributed "the same" between different intervals, so the integral we get should be $\sqrt{2}$ times the integral of the function which is $1$ on the rationals in $[0,1]$. But with the left hand integral rule with uniform partitions, this function has integral zero! So now we can horizontally stretch a "region" by a factor and not multiply its "area" by that same factor. This is very bad!

Introducing tagging into the definition makes it so that these extremely discontinuous functions are defined to not be Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you think the following: The area of the shape $B$ under the curve $y=f(x)\geq0$ $(a\leq x\leq b)$ is just $=F(b)-F(a)$ with $F$ a primitive of $f$. Why should I bother then with tagged partitions?

The point is this: The formula
$${\rm area}(B)=F(b)-F(a)\ ,$$
called the **Fundamental Theorem of Calculus**, is a true mathematical miracle, and you need these partitions to prove it.

In addition, these partitions and the corresponding Riemann sums give approximate values for the desired area in cases where you cannot find an elementary primitive $F$.

Comment: In other words, what is really remarkable is that integration (in the sense of computing *areas*, not computing antiderivatives) has anything to do with derivatives in the first place. Having seen the standard treatment of calculus, it is easy to miss this.